# Transparent PNG in ImageView using hardwareAccelerated true in the manifest

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make a ImageView over a custom `jpg` background.

My `ImageView` source is a transparent `PNG`.

I did this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnFlash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/off"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And it's worked.

But I need to turn on in my manifest this feature:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

When I turn it to true my ImageView lose its transparency.

How can I do it with `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`?

Answer (score 1):

When you enable hardware acceleration globally specifying in the manifest file, you can still enable or disable hardware acceleration locally at the Activity / Window / View level for fine-grained control. (See [official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel).)

So, by disabling hardware acceleration of the ImageView and/or the LinearLayout specifying `View.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`, your problem may be solved.

```
View imageView = findViewById(R.id.btnFlash);
imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

View linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
linearLayout.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Comment: thank you. and if my hardware acceleration globally is false how can i set to enable for a specific linear layout?

Comment: @JasarOrion you can use `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)` on the layout.

Comment: my image is keeping with white bg when I enable any hardware acceleration in the app